# What specifically changed with ActiveStorage config in Rails 6.1 to make it throw 'wrong number of arguments' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-activestorage

I am upgrading a rails app from `6.0.6.1` to `6.1.7.3`. I am following the upgrade steps carefully, but when attempting to run the generated migration files for ActiveStorage, I am getting the error: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)`. This also happens when I navigate to any view in the app that calls an attachment. Example: `post.image.attached?`

The line in the migration that throws the error is: `ActiveStorage::Blob.service.name`

The `activestorage` version is the same as the new rails version in `gemfile.lock`. The `storage.yml` file for development is:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

and the only other config, which is in `development.rb` is: `config.active_storage.service = :local`

Am I missing something to get this working?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm still on ruby 2.7.7.

Comment: Would be useful to include the migration and the error backtrace.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, the backtrace in the migration didn't have any clues, but when I ran the same line in the rails console, it showed the gem as the source.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There was an ancient un-maintained gem in the gemfile called `has_secure_token`. Once I removed that, the migrations ran successfully and ActiveStorage works normally.